# Is it safe to put database password in $_SERVER?

Tags: php, symfony

I am learning Symfony2, and if i refer to `The Symfony CookBook` (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html) they tell us to put sensitive options (like database password and user) outside of Symfony.

It is safe to put that informations on `$_SERVER` ?

```
SetEnv          SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER user
SetEnv          SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD password
```

If yes (or no), why?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: More or less. It is certainly safer than a lot of other places you could put it.

Comment: imo this is nonsense. wonder why they advertise that. In that case for example you would need to reload the web server if you want to change the database password - for no advantage.

Comment: @hek2mgl Why is it nonsense?

Comment: Let me answer with a question: Why should it make sense?

Comment: It means that there is no file that could accidentally be downloaded or passed around with the details for the server. Also when you changed any parameters you would need to regenerate the cache anyway, so a server reload would be far less of an issue.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed the cache. I still think having the configs in yaml or xml, even outside of the web folder is more suitable than having the configs in the vhost config as shown. Especially if command line and web applications would need to access the same configs (true for symfony). Also note: having the configs in environment variables (like shown on the linked docu page) makes it possible to other users to see them in `/proc/PID/environ`

Comment: Your answer was helpful @hek2mgl, i think having the configs outside of web folder is enough and maybe more secure than doing that, thanks you

Comment: You are welcome. I would place all web accessible stuff into `PROJECT/web` and configs under `PROJECT/config` where `PROJECT/web` is the document root.

Comment: If you host multiple Symfony2 applications on single server this would indeed make no sense, right? Unless you use separate environment variable for each of those?

Answer (score 0):

Every PaaS platform (elasticbeanstalk, heroku, etc..) uses Environment Variables (in php accessible via $_SERVER and getenv function). IMO if you disable phpinfo function in production (because everybody loves to create file info.php in root dir;]) it's a pretty safe place to hold password.

Comment: Haha love the part "because everybody loves to create file info.php in root dir;" :D